# the task is not synchronized in makefile. how can I fix that?

Tags: makefile

I have a task in makefile as follows.

```
out.tar: 
  $(eval TMP := $(shell aws iam get-role --role-name test1))
  @echo hi $(TMP)/hi.txt
```

the command `aws iam get-role --role-name test1` returns `A client error (ExpiredToken) occurred when calling the GetRole operation: The security token included in the request is expired`.

But I always got `hi /hi.txt`. the $(TMP) is empty. anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: What are you expecting to be in `TMP`? The error message?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes

Comment: You should be able to catch the error by redirecting stderr to stdout, something like; `$(eval TMP := $(shell aws iam get-role --role-name test1 2>&1))`.

Comment: thanks very much, it works to me

Answer (score 1):

Moving the comment to an answer;

If you want to capture `stderr` in a [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), you need to use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout (which is normally what is captured)

```
$(eval TMP := $(shell aws iam get-role --role-name test1 2>&1))
```